How could the subspace topology $T'$ on $R$ as a subspace of $X$ be a discrete topology?
This is from example 4.5.2 of Fred's Principles of Topology.
Consider the subset $X$ of $\mathbb R^2$ consisting of real axis $\mathbb R$ and one additional point $a = (0,1)$. Define a topology $T$ on $X$ to consist of the empty set $\emptyset$ and all subsets of $X$ which contain $a$.
How could the subspace topology $T'$ on $\mathbb R$ as a subspace of $X$ be a discrete topology? I could only understand that $T'$ must contain only close sets, but I don't understand how it could be a discrete topology. I try to look for an answer everywhere but cannot find it.

If $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ then $A\cup \{a\}$ is open in $X$. Hence, its intersection with $\mathbb R$ is open in the subspace topology of $\mathbb R$. But $\mathbb R \cap (A\cup \{a\})=A$  proving that every subset of $\mathbb R$ is open in $\mathbb R$.

Thanks. You also correct my wrong understanding that the subspace topology of $\mathbb R$ must contain only close sets.
